# Trying to send a GET request, getting 301 to the same address

Tags: c++, sockets, http, redirect

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request in C++ using sockets, and I'm getting in response a 301 Moved permently, but to the same address I've asked for!

Here is my GET request :

```
GET /watch?v=1cQh1ccqu8M HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Firefox/29.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language:en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection: keep-alive
```

All the `\r\n` are perfectly in place, because this GET request used to work for me not long ago, and I have not touched it since...

The response I'm getting from youtube :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 11:04:10 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cQh1ccqu8M
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=151657&hl=en for more info."
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.002
```

According to the page they tell me to check `http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=151657&hl=en`, it says I need to add some kind of cookies now?

I've allways send this request without sending any cookies, so I am a bit confused...

Comment: Was your original request really done with https and not plain http? And since your problem is not related to P3P you can ignore the P3P header information, they are not related to your problem.

Comment: No, I was connecting to `www.youtube.com', then I've sent the GET request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> me: Was your original request really done with https and not plain http...
>
> @Amit: No, I was connecting to `www.youtube.com', then I've sent the GET request

Then you should look more closely at the redirect:

```
Location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cQh1ccqu8M
```

As you can see, this does redirect you to the same host, same page, but different protocol: you must use https instead of http.

Comment: How can I connect into https then, using Winsock? I'm using the WinAPI function `gethostbyname` to determine the server's IP, and in the port I put 443 for SSL (right?)

Comment: Yes, 443 is correct. And for doing SSL with winsock see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170861/ssl-api-for-winsock